# Graph API Limit Exceeded

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We have an application which displays user's album + photos + posts. User can further filter this content. Our issue is that some time for heavy FB user we are getting limit exceeded error.

To have a work around of this situation what we were planning to require use to login again use FB.login() function in a hope that we get new access token and again we can query the data.

But this approach is not working for us.

Is there any other way we can get around this problem?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Limits are there for a _reason_. If anyone could just circumvent them when they feel like they “need” to, having limits would be kinda superfluous in the first place …

Answer (score 0):

Top of the head:

- Use FQL multiquery to obtain data in larger batches
- Use the `?ids=<CSV LIST OF IDS>` syntax in the Graph API documentation to retrieve data for several objects at once

If those are already in place and you're still hitting limits, just throttle your calls and slowly make the necessary calls in the background over the space of a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give advice without knowing exactly what you're doing, but the general advice is to reduce the number of API calls you're making.  So, check that you're not querying the same data more than once. Also, if you're querying data that doesn't change very often you could cache it on your server to avoid calling Facebook each time you need that data.